# Security issue in Kopal connect

Tags: security, protocols

There is a social networking protocol called [Kopal Connect](http://code.google.com/p/kopal/wiki/Kopal_Connect). Is this method a problem, the friend request looks like this `http://alice.example.net/profile/?kopal.connect=true&kopal.subject=friendship-request&kopal.identity=http://bob.example.org/profile/`, and as far as I know it can be requested for your name with an embedded image or iframe when you visit a malicious web site.

Comment: It's worth noting that the last update was from 2 years ago. Perhaps you should invest your resources in another protocol with a larger userbase.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [example documentation for a kopal connect friend request](http://code.google.com/p/kopal/wiki/Kopal_Connect#Example).  I would say that this request is probably vulnerable to [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29).  However the impact is minor,  its more of an annoyance users because Alice still needs to approve the friendship request.   In order to carry out this CSRF attack you still need the `friendship key` for Alice and it maybe difficult to automate this step in the process.